# How to display String constant value in the Log

Tags: android, android-resources

I have constant String values in the strings.xml, and I want to display some of these values from the Log.i. I tried the following

```
Log.w(TAG, Integer.toString(R.String.bt_value));
```

But at run time, what is getting displayed is "R.String.bt_value"

How to display that value correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retrieve a `String` from **R.string.xxx** (one of resource xml files), use `getResources().getString(id)`.

```
Log.w(TAG, getResources().getString(R.String.bt_value));
```